# Sql Server 2012 SSIS Integration Services Catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am getting the following error when trying to create the IS Catalog in Sql Server 2012 SSIS.

```
> TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services
------------------------------

Operation 'Create' on object 'CatalogFolder[@Name='DeployTest']' failed during execution. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60+((SQL11_RTM).120210-1917+)&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

------------------------------

The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. (Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient)

------------------------------

Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401) (Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I am not very savvy with SQL Server and am new to SSIS.  I am simply trying to do a test demo project to familiarize myself with it as I have written a WCF Service to execute the SSIS package once it's created but am unable to complete the tutorial due to this issue.

I've seen a similar problem on the internet when googling for the solution but it was for SQL 2005 and nothing on 2012.

As a non-DBA person, how can I configure SSIS on SQL 2012?

Answer (score 0):

I added the Folder under the Integration Services Catalog in Sql Management Studio rather than through the deployment wizard through visual studio 2010 and it worked.  If anyone else has this issue try doing it through Sql Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because the user that the SQL Instance was running under appeared not to have the correct authority.